# c++ delete linked list not woking properly

Tags: c++

I am having the following linked list structure

```
struct MyClass {
      int i;
      string str;
      uint64_t address;
    };
```

And in main,

```
int main () {  
  MyClass * pt;  

  pt = new MyClass;  
 pt->i = 10;  
pt->str = "test";  
pt->address = 2343233233;  
  delete pt;

  return 0;  
}
```

The problem is, after deleting pt, this is the result i got.

```
i = 323322;  
str = "";  
address = 2343233233;
```

variable i is having junk value, str is null and address remains same. Does anybody know why is it like this and how to solve it?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: set pt to nullptr after you delete it or you'll have a dangling pointer, pointing to something that doesn't exists anymore

Comment: ***The problem is, after deleting pt, this is the result i got.*** After deleting pt you have Undefined Behavior when you try to derefrence the pointer meaning the value of i can be anything at all. Your program can crash ... or it can give you some random value or even the previous value of i.

Comment: ***and how to solve it??*** Don't use pt after you delete avoiding the UB.

Answer (score 3):

There's no solving this, as there's no error(*).

You're allocating a block of memory for an instance of your class, setting some values there and then freeing that memory.

After you called `delete pt;`, the address pointed to by the pointer `pt` is no longer intended to be used by you, writing or even reading from there may cause undefined behaviour. In theory the programm could send ninjas to kill you. In practice most often you're just accessing that very same memory location, only that using it will lead to catastrophic failure.

What you see are most probably the changes internal bookkeeping of the memory allocator has performed after freeing.

As a final note: I really don't know where you've seen that, but your class is absolutely not how you should implement a linked list:

```
struct listnode {
  // some data
  listnode * next;
  // better: std::unique_ptr<listnode> next;
  // or with sharing: std::shared_ptr<listnode> next;
};
```

There's a reason for pointers.

(*) **to clarify:** there's no error, as the programm is showing a form of undefined behaviour, which is exactly what it should do in this form (when dereferencing after delete).